# Button with 2 texts, binding via controltemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, controltemplate

I want to make multiple buttons like this

```
<Button>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Column="0" name="lblShortcut">F1</Label>
        <Label Grid.Column="1" name="lblText">search</Label>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

So I know that I have to work with something like a Template, and I want to bind those buttons to a class like this:

```
class SearchButtonContent
{
    public string Shortcut { get ; set; }
    public string Text { get ; set; }
}
```

In such way that a `Shortcut` is bound to `lblShortcut` and `Text` to `lblText`. What is the best way to achieve this with elegant templates, with the possibility to make those buttons in code at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the data for the buttons programmatically then you should use [ContentTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplate%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property which is of type DataTemplate

And the only thing you need is to assign Button.Content the instance of SearchButtonContent class.

```
<Button>
    <Button.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label Grid.Column="0" name="lblShortcut" Content="{Binding Shortcut }"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="1" name="lblText" Content="{Binding Text}"/>
            </Grid>

        </DataTemplate>
    </Button.ContentTemplate>
</Button>
```